# Pass external variable as field in $cond aggregation mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection in mongo db something like this

```
{
    buckets: {
        "1-10": {
            base: 10,
            cutoff: 100
        },
        "11-20": {
            base: 20,
            cutoff: 200
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a query such that the bucket can be easily accessible.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      bucket_value: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  { $gt: [{ computedBucketValue }, 0] },
                  { $lt: [{ computedBucketValue }, 51] },
                ],
              },
              then: {
                $ifNull: ["$buckets.1-10.base", "First bucket"],
              },
            },
          ],
          default: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      bucket_value: "$bucket_value",
      _id: 0,
    },
  },
])
```

`computedBucketValue` is already calculated and that field is not directly available in the collection. Can someone help me with how to use the external variable in the place of field key. This query is just a simple query. The are so many buckets and I'm preparing these conditions in js before sending it to aggregate query.

Comment: Consider changing your schema if possible as using dynamic values as field names cause unnecessary complexity to queries. Also, if you are having a lot of buckets stored in a single document, you may exceed [MongoDB 16MB single document size limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size). Consider a schema at bucket level like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P0Hrl0XMWTY)

Comment: Why do you use `$switch`? You have only a single `case`, thus a simple [$cond](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) (ie. simple if-then-else) should be sufficient.

Comment: What is the purpose of `{ $lt: [{ $literal: 10 }, 51] }`? 10 is always lower than 51, so this is rather pointless. The same applies for `{ $gt: [{ computedBucketValue }, 0] }` - `computedBucketValue` is a (constant) calculated value, which is either always or never greater than 0

Comment: Do you have a sample value for `computedBucketValue` and desired output?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit `{ $lt: [{ $literal: 10 }, 51] }` is added by mistake. I have updated the query. I am identifying the bucket based on the conditions by making the comparisons of `computedBucketValue` with ranges. Like @ray suggested, I'll check about the schema for bucket level too.

Comment: There are so many conditional cases added to `$switch`. I just posted one case here to understand it easily.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB aggregation, if you want to use a field key that is determined by an external variable (in your case, "computedBucketValue"), you can achieve this using the $objectToArray and $filter operators. Here's how you can modify your aggregation query to dynamically access the bucket using an external variable:

```
var computedBucketValue = 25; // External variable

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      bucket_value: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: { $objectToArray: "$buckets" },
                  as: "bucket",
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      { $gt: [computedBucketValue, "$$bucket.v.base"] },
                      { $lte: [computedBucketValue, "$$bucket.v.cutoff"] },
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
              as: "matchedBucket",
              in: "$$matchedBucket.k", // Extract the key of the matched bucket
            },
          },
          0
        ],
      },
      _id: 0,
    },
  }
]);
```

Comment: This looks like a LLM answer